# On sums of minima and maxima

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, rational-functions

Let $h_1,\ldots,h_n$ be positive integers, and define
$$m(h_1,\ldots,h_n)=\sum_{r_1=0}^{h_1-1}\ldots\sum_{r_n=0}^{h_n-1}\min\left\{\frac{r_1}{h_1},\ldots,\frac{r_n}{h_n}\right\}$$
and
$$M(h_1,\ldots,h_n)=\sum_{r_1=0}^{h_1-1}\ldots\sum_{r_n=0}^{h_n-1}\max\left\{\frac{r_1}{h_1},\ldots,\frac{r_n}{h_n}\right\}.$$
Motivated by Dedekind sums, I introduced $m(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ and $M(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ in [my paper in Discrete Math. 257(2002), 143-159](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(01)00476-9), and determined their exact values for $n\le 3$ in that paper. For example, I showed that if $h,k,l$ are positive integers then
\begin{align} m(h,k,l)=&\frac{hkl}4-\frac{hk+hl+kl}6+\frac{h+k+l-1}8
\\&+\frac{h+k-2hk}{24l}+\frac{h+l-2hl}{24k}+\frac{k+l-2kl}{24h}
\\&+\frac{(h-1)(k,l)^2}{24kl}+\frac{(k-1)(h,l)^2}{24hl}+\frac{(l-1)(h,k)^2}{24hk},
\end{align}
where $(a,b)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of integers $a$ and $b$.

QUESTION. Are $m(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ and $M(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ rational functions in $h_1,\ldots,h_n$ whenever $h_1,\ldots,h_n$ are pairwise coprime?

I conjectured that this question has a positive answer in the mentioned 2002 paper of mine.

Any ideas towards the solution? Your comments are welcome!